# Check if language $L^2$ is regular

Tags: regular-language

$L=\{w|w\in\{0,1\}^*\wedge \#_1(w)=\#_2(w)\}$, where $\#_a(w)$ denotes number of symbol $a$ in word $w$.   Check if $L^2$ is regular.

So idea is: $L^2 \cap 0^*1^*0^*=\{0^n1^{2n}0^n|n\ge 0 \}\notin Reg$
The fact that intersection is not regular is easy to show using pumping lemma. So due to the fact that regular languages are closer under intersection and $0^*1^*0^*$ is regular we conclude that $L^2$ is irregular.

What about this solution ?

Comment: If $L^2=\{ww:w\in L\}$, then this is almost right: you need $n\ge 0$, not $n>0$, in the description of $L^2\cap 0^*1^*0^*$.

Comment: yes, you are right. I corrected it.

Comment: Looks fine now.